# Bypass DocuSign Form/UI, automatically submit signature

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to find out if it is possible to bypass displaying the form/DocuSign UI and attach our form submit button to the "Sign" tab action on the DocuSign UI. Here is our proposed process:

1) Customer follows link to our site, fills out our HTML form and clicks "Submit."

2) If the customer is registered with DocuSign, the form is signed automatically and they are taken to our Thank You page. Otherwise, the "Adopt Your Signature" modal is displayed like so:

[image]

After they click "Adopt & Sign", we want to "Finish" the DocuSign process automatically and close the modal.

Can anyone tell me if this is even possible to do without displaying the form/DocuSign UI?

Thanks in advance for your patience!

Comment: Signing (whether the signer has a saved signature or first time adopting one) is an explicit event. The recipient must click on the signature tab to either apply the saved signature, or adopt a new one.

Answer (score 1):

As Luis Scott commented, "auto-sign" is not offered by the DocuSign DTM service. DocuSign's customer (your app) can authenticate the signer, but the signer still needs to participate in the DocuSign UX to sign the document.

If auto-sign is an essential issue for your use case, you can investigate CoSign Central from DocuSign. CoSign Central enables your app to digitally sign a document. But for signers who are external to your organization, creating a digital certificate for the signers can become tricky. For internal signers, CoSign Central can be a very good answer.